# MYSQL: Selecting between null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the following statement:

```
SELECT hl.hour, hl.hourlistex, HOUR(ts.`Timestamp`) as Hour, COUNT(DISTINCT ts.`ForsNr`) as Count, SUM(ts.`TotalAmount`) as SumByReceipt
FROM hourlist hl
LEFT JOIN transactions ts on hl.hour = HOUR(ts.`Timestamp`) AND ts.`SoldDate` = '2016-07-12'
GROUP by hl.hour
```

Result:

```
hour    hourlistex  Hour    Count   SumByReceipt
9         9-10      NULL       0    NULL
10        10-11     NULL       0    NULL
11        11-12     NULL       0    NULL
12        12-13     12         2    152.0000
13        13-14     NULL       0    NULL
14        14-15     14         7    545.0000
15        15-16     15         8    843.0000
16        16-17     16         9    492.0000
17        17-18     17         12   868.0000
18        18-19     18         5    448.0000
19        19-20     NULL       0    NULL
20        20-21     NULL       0    NULL
21        21-22     NULL       0    NULL
22        22-23     NULL       0    NULL
```

Im looking for a way to get the result, without the starting and ending NULLs, but including NULLs within.

Like:

```
hour    hourlistex  Hour    Count   SumByReceipt
12        12-13     12         2    152.0000
13        13-14     NULL       0    NULL
14        14-15     14         7    545.0000
15        15-16     15         8    843.0000
16        16-17     16         9    492.0000
17        17-18     17         12   868.0000
18        18-19     18         5    448.0000
```

Is that possible to achieve with a Mysql statement? Im familiar with BETWEEN arguments but dont know if it works in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but you can do it with a separate `join`:

```
SELECT hl.hour, hl.hourlistex, HOUR(ts.`Timestamp`) as Hour, COUNT(DISTINCT ts.`ForsNr`) as Count, SUM(ts.`TotalAmount`) as SumByReceipt
FROM hourlist hl LEFT JOIN
     transactions ts
     on hl.hour = HOUR(ts.`Timestamp`) AND ts.`SoldDate` = '2016-07-12' CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT max(hour(ts.timestamp)) as maxtsh, min(hour(ts.timestamp)) as mintsh
      FROM transactions ts
      WHERE ts.`SoldDate` = '2016-07-12'
     ) tts
WHERE h1.hour >= tts.mintsh and h1.hour < tts.maxtsh + 1 
GROUP by hl.hour;
```

The `tts` derived table aggregates the transactions to get the earliest and latest hour on the date.

Comment: I tried your statement but I get the exact same result as before. What am I missing?

Comment: @Tronik . . . That should not have been a `left join`.

Comment: Very nice, thank you, works! Do you have time for a brief explanation?

Comment: @Tronik . . . The additional subquery calculates the minimum and maximum hour.  This is then used for filtering the final result.